# SSD issue on macbook pro

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I tried to install FreeBSD on a Macbook pro 2015(early) and it totally formatted my SSD.

When I tried to rollback to macOS from the recovery menu, I cant see my SSD(although the laptop is working with freeBSD).

Is there a way to hard format the disk to the apple file system instead of trying to find my way around with the recovery menu?

Essentially, I want to make the SSD visible to the recovery menu so I can go back to macos.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: From the recovery boot, if you open the disk utility, Presentation Menu / Show all devices, do you see your SSD and if so, by selecting it, can you erase it and reformat it APFS partition scheme GUID?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

1. Boot to the recovery partition, open disk utility and delete the other non-recovery permissions and then create a new JHFS+ / APFS depending on the macOS version.  (credit Jean_JD in a comment)
2. Create an external macOS Installer flash drive. Hold the Option key and boot from the flash drive then delete the internal disk entirely including the recovery partition then install macOS. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372
3. Boot to Internet Recovery Mode,If you use Shift-Option-Command-R during startup, you're offered the macOS that came with your Mac, or the closest version still available. If you use Option-Command-R during startup, in most cases you're offered the latest macOS that is compatible with your Mac. Otherwise you're offered the macOS that came with your Mac, or the closest version still available. Connect to WiFi and delete the foreign FreeBSD partitions and install.